# compile and install opencv on raspberry pi 3 model B

Tags: opencv

i'm facing a problem while i'm installing opencv version 3.1.0 and python 3 ...
I followed the steps from here : https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/
I followed every step with no problems except when i'm trying to install opencv libraries (make -j4) it stops at 8%
I tried to clean make and do it again but still it didn't work!
what should i do

```
[  8%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_RELEASE.gch
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_algo.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/algorithm:62,
                 from /home/wejdan/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:53,
                 from /home/wejdan/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /home/wejdan/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:52,
                 from /home/wejdan/opencv-**3.1.0/build/modules/core/precomp.hpp:49:
/usr/include/c++/10/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   75 | #include_next <stdlib.h>**
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/build.make:83: modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_RELEASE.gch] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3936: modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2
```

Comment: `fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory` - guessing you didn't install all the prerequisites - `build-essential` would be my first try. Also, 7 year old instructions for ancient version of raspbian may have other issues

Comment: I suggest you install from the standard repositories.

Comment: Why would you follow an ancient post from a random site for an obsolete OS rather than searching this site?